# PHP User Submitted Data in text box

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out how in PHP/MySQL to have a text box where someone can type content in and save it, and it will just store whatever was typed last in the text box on the front end.

I assume some type of form would be best like: (but not sure what all is needed in the backend.)

```
<form action="process.php" method="post"> 
    Manager: <input type="text" name="manager"><br> 
    Tech: <input type="text" name = "tech"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Update"> 
 </form>
```

Comment: You will have to save the data to a file or database of some sort.  Just google `php save database` or `php save data to file` and you will find a number of ways.  Then, you can retrieve the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straightforward tutorial showing how to collect user input on a HTML form and store it in a backend MySQL database using PHP. Read through it and you'll have a better understanding of what you need to do:

http://brian.dobberteen.com/code/using-php-and-mysql-to-create-a-simple-contact-form-and-results-browser/

You already have a good start above - a HTML form submitting input to `process.php`. Now you need to implement PHP code in `process.php` that takes the data from the form and saves in to MySQL. The tutorial explains how to do this.